# Set Input array value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement html **input array**.

```
<input type="text" name="firstName[]" id="firstName[]">
```

And i need to set value of another form which looks something like

```
<form id="tempForm">
   <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
   <input type="text" name="userId" id="userId">
</form>
```

into the `input array` using jquery on form submit.

For that i tried following on form submit,

```
var currentIndex=$("input[name^=firstName]").length;
$("#firstName").eq(currentIndex).val($("#userName").val());
```

But it doesn't works,obviously.

Question:

How to set value of input array using jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the jquery append function for add inputs with different attribute value :
Check it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var a = ["username","userid"];
var b = ["username","userid"];

for( var i =  ; i <3 ; i++){
   $('#tempForm').append('<input type="text" name="'+a[i]+'" id="'+b[i]+'" />);
}

});
```

Then continue your other work:

replace this code with your js code :

```
var currentIndex=$("input[name^=firstName]").length;
$("#firstName").eq(currentIndex).val($("#"+userName).val());
```

Comment: `$("#"+userName).val()`. 
`userName` may an undifened variable.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @VahidTaghizadeh but i am looking for an input array implementation and it doesn't seems to follow that pattern.

Comment: you miss a single quotes on this line -> `$('#tempForm').append('<input...`